# How to connect QGIS to PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

I want to establish connexion QGIS and PostGIS in order to run the pgRouting Layer, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a detailed article here](http://gis-techniques.blogspot.fr/2012/04/how-to-connect-spatial-databasepostgis.html), does it answer your question ?

One part is about connecting from QGIS by adding a postgis layer, the other part is about installing Postgis inside PostGreSQL